# JSC_TRAILING_COMMA: Parse error. IE8 (and below) - Can jshint warning me for left trailing comma?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, google-closure-compiler, jshint, google-closure

Using [Google Closure Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/) I get this error:

```
JSC_TRAILING_COMMA: Parse error. IE8 (and below) will parse trailing commas in array and object literals incorrectly. If you are targeting newer versions of JS, set the appropriate language_in option. at line 7 character 9
        },
```

for the following code:

```
App.prototype = {
    testA: function () {

    },
    testB: function () {

    },
};
```

I would like to know if [jshint](http://jshint.com/) has some build-in option to detect tailing commas and show a warning message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSHint will warn you ["Extra comma. (it breaks older versions of IE)"](http://jslinterrors.com/extra-comma) if you set the `es3` option (in version 2.0.0 and later):

```
/*jshint es3: true */
var x = {
    prop1: 10,
    prop2: 20,
};
```

In older versions of JSHint you don't need to set the `es3` option as it's the default. All versions of JSLint will also give a similar warning.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you have any idea if it is possible to use detect "estra comma' also in jscs instead of JShint? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: @GibboK - Yes, it is. Have a look at the [JSCS docs](http://jscs.info/rules.html#disallowtrailingcomma).

Comment: Here a related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29120520/disallowtrailingcomma-does-not-work-in-jscs I would really appreciate if you could have a look at it if you have time. Thanks in advance.